# Need double quotes for titles in References at some places

Tags: bibtex, natbib

Here is MWE which returns me two references citations. The article citation appears in single quote and I want double. For the conference, I need the conference title in Italics and correct the word "in" from italics to normal.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,Times]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\begin{document}

The first reference is  \citep{AAA} where I need to put Double Quotes in the title.
In the next ref \citep{BBB} I need the title of proceeding to be in italics.

\bibliography{biblio}{}
\end{document}
```

and the bibtex file...

```
@ARTICLE{AAA,
  author = {Authors1},
  title = {The title of the paper},
  journal = {A Journal},
  year = {2000},
  volume = {1111},
  pages = {111--222},
  number = {5}
}

@CONFERENCE{BBB,
  author = {Authors2},
  title = {\enquote{The title of second citation}},
  booktitle = {International Conference},
  year = {2000},
  address = {Country},
  month = {Month}
}
```

Comment: You don't format inside your *.bib file. This is done by the bibliography style you tell your bibliography package to use (in oyur case natbib). I would highly suggest to use biblatex however, since this is really much more easier to handle and provides several very good styles out of the box.

Comment: @HATEthePLOT

I have removed commands for quotations from bibtex file. But \usepackage{biblatex} is not working with  \bibliographystyle{agsm} ...
what do I do ?

Comment: Please take a look at the package documentation. Some things are handled differently by biblatex.

Answer (score 1):

With biblatex your MWE should look like this and should provide your requests out of the box (cf. [here](https://residual.nsupdate.info/owncloud/index.php/s/iaRmRgNqYEHbk7M)):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,Times]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}

The first reference is  \parencite{AAA} where I need to put Double Quotes in the title.
In the next ref \parencite{BBB} I need the title of proceeding to be in italics.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Still getting the following error...

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\biblatex.cfg")))
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...docsvlist \expandafter {\bbl@loaded 
                                                  }\ifboolexpr { not test {\...
l.7 \begin{document}
                    
? 

Process has been terminated ...

Comment: Can you give more details from the log please?

Comment: The log file is too long and quote only the a few more lines from within ... Cannot pastethe full log here...


Package biblatex Warning: No "backend" specified, using Biber backend.
(biblatex)                To use BibTeX, load biblatex with 
(biblatex)                the "backend=bibtex" option.

Comment: ok this is actually enough. It tells you to specify a backkend where you can choose between bibtex or biber.
`\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}` should do the trick. Be aware that you have to run `biber` instead of `bibtex` to create your bibliography.